# Flutter: How do I remove Provider not found & Invalid Qualifier error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I run my code for debugging I got this errors. If you know about it, please tell me how to remove this error.

**This is an error:**

```
      Restarted application in 1,191ms.
W/DynamiteModule( 6043): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6043): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6043): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 6043): callback not found for CALLBACK_AVAILABLE message
D/skia    ( 6043):    1 Shader compilation error
D/skia    ( 6043):    2 ------------------------
D/skia    ( 6043):    3    1    #version 300 es
D/skia    ( 6043):    4    2
D/skia    ( 6043):    5    3    #extension GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch : require
D/skia    ( 6043):    6    4    precision mediump float;
D/skia    ( 6043):    7    5    precision mediump sampler2D;
D/skia    ( 6043):    8    6    inout mediump vec4 sk_FragColor;
D/skia    ( 6043):    9    7    flat in mediump vec4 vcolor_Stage0;
D/skia    ( 6043):   10    8    void main() {
D/skia    ( 6043):   11    9        mediump vec4 outputColor_Stage0;
D/skia    ( 6043):   12   10        outputColor_Stage0 = vcolor_Stage0;
D/skia    ( 6043):   13   11        {
D/skia    ( 6043):   14   12            mediump vec4 _dstColor = sk_FragColor;
D/skia    ( 6043):   15   13            mediump vec4 _0_result = outputColor_Stage0 + (1.0 - outputColor_Stage0.w) * _dstColor;
D/skia    ( 6043):   16   14            _0_result.xyz = max(_0_result.xyz, (1.0 - _dstColor.w) * outputColor_Stage0.xyz + _dstColor.xyz);
D/skia    ( 6043):   17   15            sk_FragColor = _0_result;
D/skia    ( 6043):   18   16        }
D/skia    ( 6043):   19   17    }
D/skia    ( 6043):   20   18
D/skia    ( 6043):   21 Errors:
D/skia    ( 6043):   22 ERROR: 0:6: 'inout' : invalid qualifier: can be only used with function parameters
D/skia    ( 6043):   23
```